# command line variable not picked up by dev_prod_switch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to use the following grunt plugin to enable me to use includes linking to compressed files for my production build, and uncompressed for my dev build.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-prod-switch

Below is a very abbreviated version of my Gruntfile:
    ...
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-dev-prod-switch');

```
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
    ...
    dev_prod_switch: {
        options: {
            environment: 'dev',
            env_char: '#',
            env_block_dev: 'env:dev',
            env_block_prod: 'env:prod'
        },
        dynamic_mappings: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'dist',
                src: ['*.html', 'js/includes.js', 'js/includes.min.js'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }]
        }
    },
    ....
    // Full distribution task.
    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['...', '...', 'dev_prod_switch']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['...', '...', '...', 'dev_prod_switch']);
});
```

In my HTML file I am using:

And in my includes.js file:

```
var path;
/* env:dev */
    path = "js/pageScripts/dashboard.js";
/* env:dev:end */
/* env:prod */
    path = "js/pageScripts/dashboard.min.js"
/* env:prod:end */
plenty_admin.REST.loadScript(path, function(){
     ....
});
```

I trigger my build on the commandline using:

```
grunt prod --env=prod
```

or

```
grunt dev --env=dev
```

This has no effect on how the files defined in "dynamic_mappings" are processed, though if I set:

```
environment: 'prod',
```

before I compile, the files are processed correctly using the prod conditional comment I have set in my html/js file.

Perfect world would be to simply run:

```
grunt dev
```

or

```
grunt prod
```

and see the output files processed as expected, but adding the environment variable to the end is not a problem if it can't be avoided.

```
grunt prod --env=prod
```

or

```
grunt dev --env=dev
```

Any help appreciated, and happy to add more details if necessary - I'm a bit of a node / grunt noob I'm afraid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the examples found in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-prod-switch)...

Change the `options` object as follows:

```js
options: {
    environment: grunt.option('env') || 'dev', // <-- Change value to this !
    env_char: '#',
    env_block_dev: 'env:dev',
    env_block_prod: 'env:prod'
}
```

**Note:** This sets the option according to the flag provided via the CLI. When the value is set to `'dev'` (*as shown in the code above*) this means that `dev` will be the default value used when ***no*** option flag is provided. Further info can be found in  [grunt.options](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option).

Comment: Thanks RobC, again, appreciated.